# ¿Cómo se denominan coloquialmente las "atracciones" a nivel local?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, diferencias-regionales, sustantivos

Técnicamente, en español tenemos la palabra *[atracción](https://dle.rae.es/atracci%C3%B3n)* para designar:

> Cada una de las instalaciones recreativas, como los carruseles, casetas de tiro al blanco, toboganes, etc., que se montan en la feria de una población y que, reunidas en un lugar estable, constituyen un parque de atracciones. U. m. en pl.

Sin embargo, cuando llega la Feria de Sevilla y montan la zona de atracciones, conocida aquí popularmente como la "[Calle del Infierno](https://www.sevilla.org/fiestas-de-la-ciudad/feria-de-sevilla/feria-de-abril/el-recinto-ferial/calle-del-infierno)", nunca digo que voy a llevar a los niños a las atracciones, sino a los [cacharritos](https://fititu.es/definicion/sevilla-2/alcal-de-guadaira/cacharritos-3/). Y recientemente he descubierto que incluso dentro de Andalucía hay distintas formas de denominarlos, según la provincia.

Por tanto, y viendo que esta puede ser la típica palabra que varíe regionalmente, ¿cómo se denominan coloquialmente las atracciones de feria en tu zona?

Comment: En Málaga capital también los llamamos "cacharritos" :-) (Actualizo wiki)

Answer (score 3):

> Esta respuesta es *community wiki*, eso quiere decir que cualquiera la puede editar para añadir más contenido. Siéntete libre de aportar tus conocimientos (si es posible, con algún enlace que verifique la información) y así ampliar la lista.

### Chile

- Los juegos (En plural. Supongo que es un acortamiento de "juegos mecánicos".)

### España

#### Asturias

- [Caballitos](https://www.lavozdeasturias.es/noticia/aviles/2018/01/26/crisis-caballitos-dejara-aviles-ferial-tercera-vez-ano/00031517000205663137212.htm)

#### Granada

- [Columpios](https://www.granadahoy.com/vivir/Dia-columpios-baratos-dia-ilusion-feria-Corpus-Granada_0_1692733035.html)

#### País Vasco, Navarra

- [Barracas](https://sanfermines.net/contenido/las-barracas/es/753)

#### Sevilla, Huelva, Málaga

- [Cacharritos](https://fititu.es/definicion/sevilla-2/alcal-de-guadaira/cacharritos-3/)

Answer (score 2):

¡Hola!

En el País Vasco se utiliza mucho la palabra [barraca](https://dle.rae.es/barraca) que por lo que veo viene recogida en la RAE con la acepción de "*Construcción provisional desmontable, que se destina a espectáculos, diversiones, etc., en las fiestas populares.*"

No obstante, es cierto que cuando voy al sur y hablo de las barracas, nadie comprende a qué me refiero, allí tal y como comentas se conocen

Answer (score 0):

Leyendo la pregunta recordé una palabra que usábamos de niños para las fiestas del barrio, por lo general en primavera/verano, la **kermesse**. Los recuerdos son la semana de preparativos, atuendos, perfumes, y decisión de compañía para asistir al evento. Buscando en Google, no sabía que era una palabra derivada del holandés.

**Kermesse**

> Una kermés (también kermesse o quermés) (del neerlandés medio Kerkmis, compuesto de kerk, iglesia, y Mis, Misa, festival de iglesia) es una fiesta popular, generalmente barrial o de vecindario, que incluye puestos de juegos de destreza, juegos mecánicos, puestos de comida y bebida, sorteos y números artísticos, que se utiliza en muchos lugares (escuelas e iglesias, habitualmente) para recaudar fondos a favor de distintas causas o proyectos benéficos, artísticos o de acción social.

<sub>*Fuente [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerm%C3%A9s)*</sub>

Aunque si la feria de atracciones es un puesto considerablemente más grande, solíamos utilizar una abreviatura de las frases:

- *Feria de atracciones* = **Feria**
- *Parque de diversiones o atracciones* = **Parque**

Comment: La palabra es curiosa pero creo que no responde a la pregunta de Charlie, la cuál no se refiere a las fiestas, ni a las ferias ni a los parques de atracciones como conjunto sino a una o varias atracciones. Como él indica, en algunas partes de Andalucía a los coches de choque, el barco vikingo, la noria, la montaña rusa, ... se les conoce como los "cacharritos".  No parece que la palabra "kermesse" se pueda aplicar en su lugar en la frase "Lleva a los niños a la feria, que se monten en los cacharritos".

Comment: Pues si, y tal como lo mencionas: – lleva a los niños a la kermesse, que se monten en los juegos –. La pregunta refiere a localismos, en mi ciudad existían las kermesses tipo ferias con juegos y atracciones.

Comment: Localismos para la palabra "atracciones" (como "cacharritos"), no para la palabra "feria". Si en tu localidad se conocen como "juegos", deberías incluirlo en tu respuesta, así como incluirla en la wiki.